# Android & Robotium - waitForActivity doesn't fail when it's supposed to?

Tags: android, ui-automation, robotium

```
solo.clickOnButton("Login");
solo.waitForActivity("activityThatDoesntExist", 20000);
```

application navigates to an activity named "HomePageActivity", but the test passes even though the activity name is incorrect? Why does it pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

waitForActivity() returns 'false' when the Activity isn't found within the timeout period.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the test cases won't pass in case the expected activity doesn't show up, I usually add assertTrue method. like:

```
solo.clickOnButton("Login");
assertTrue(solo.waitForActivity("activityThatDoesntExist", 20000));
```

So when the expected activity doesn't exist, you can catch AssertionFailedError to fail your case.